# Существуют ли реальные алгоритмы со сложностью O(1/n)?

Tags: алгоритм, теория, сложность, асимптотика

Существуют ли **реальные** алгоритмы со сложностью O(1/n)? В голову лезет только ерунда по типу:

```
function test(n) {
  for (i=1; i<100000/n; i++) {
    dosomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Их даже в теории не существует. Потому что это ограничение сверху.

```
O(C + 1/n) = O(C) = O(1)
```

Где **C** - некоторая константа, отличная от 0.

А 0 она не может быть равна, поскольку у нас в любом случае есть накладные расходы хотя бы на получение самого **n** и какое-то его использование.

Потому что если мы не используем **n** вообще, то сложность, очевидно, от него не зависит и не может быть **O(1/n)**. А если используем, то мы хоть раз к нему обратимся и константа будет ненулевой.

---

Альтернативное обоснование: представим, что такой алгоритм есть, но тогда при удвоении **n** время его исполнения уменьшается вдвое и при достаточно большом **n** должно будет стать менее одной процессорной инструкции, что невозможно.

---

Даже в коде из вопроса

> ```
> for (i=1; i<100000/n; i++) {
> ```

что произойдёт, когда **n** превысит 100000?

У нас будет ровно 4 операции: присваивание, деление, сравнение и выход из функции. Это **O(1)** - оно уже неспособно уменьшиться с ростом **n**.

Answer (score 10):

Нет, не существует.

Сначала вспомним, что такое асимптота:

*Пусть у нас есть некая кривая y = A(x). Тогда асимптота y = B(x) — это такая кривая, к которой A как бы «прижимается» при движении в бесконечность вдоль оси x.*

*Графически это выглядит так:*

[image]

*<sup>Источник: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1-over-x-plus-x.svg</sup>*

*В данном примере прямая y = x является асимптотой для y = 1 / x + x, так как при достаточно больших x обе линии практически сливаются.*

Асимптотатическая сложность ведёт себя аналогичным образом, только вместо графиков у нас зависимость вычислительной сложности от количества элементов.

Соответственно, чтобы утверждать, что алгоритм имеет сложность *O(1 / N)*, надо, чтобы график сложности алгоритма совпадал с графиком *1 / n* **при очень больших n**. Но в этом случае *1 / n* вырождается в константу ноль. А раз у нас константа, значит и алгоритм имеет константную сложность, обозначаемую как *O(1)*.

Comment: Честно говоря, не понимаю, чем этот ответ принципиально отличается от моего...

Comment: @Qwertiy, принципиально — не знаю, но различие в точках зрения. Вы рассматриваете предел последовательности (*1/n → 0 ⇒ C + 1/n → C*). Я же рассматриваю геометрическую, более интуитивную для нематематика интерпретацию.

Comment: Если ты наберёшь 11 плюсов, мне дадут значок :D

Answer (score 0):

А вообще, есть интересный случай. В большинстве случаев говоря об асимптотике мы предполагаем возрастание аргумента. Но, строго говоря, это может быть не так. Например, если мы знаем, что область определения некоторой функции ограничена. Возьмём и реализуем деление `int(1/x)` через вычитание:

```js
function f(x) {
  for (var i=0, v=1; v>0; ++i, v-=x);
  return i;
}

console.log(f(1));
console.log(f(.5));
console.log(f(.25));
console.log(f(.125));
console.log(f(.0625));
console.log(f(.0000001));
```

В принципе можно сказать, что у этой функции асимптотика `O(1/x)`, т. е. при маленьких значениях x она будет работать очень медленно (кстати, ещё и неточно из-за накопления погрешноти). Разумеется, в случае с целым аргументом такой вариант будет невозможен.

Comment: Вот только сложность алгоритма оценивается как функция времени от количества элементов, которые нужно обработать, а не от величины единственного аргумента.

Comment: @Александр, что-то спорное утверждение. Если я перебором ищу корни уравнения, например `for (q=0; q<n; ++q) for (w=0; w<n; ++w) if (q*q+w*w=n*n) res.push([q, w])` - тут квадратичная асимптотика, а что является обрабатываемыми элементами? И второй вопрос: а какая асимптотика у функции из ответа?

Comment: По идее, функция из ответа не имеет асимптотики по размеру входящих данных, потому что этот размер есть константа.

Comment: Вообще-то теория рассматривает асимптотику при n →∞...

Comment: @Qwertiy ЕМНИП сложность - это зависимость от **объёма** (количества) обрабатываемых входных данных. В показанном случае поиска корней уравнения объём входных данных всегда равен единице (параметр `n`).

Comment: @Akina сложность итерационных алгоритмов часто рассматривают как функцию требуемой точности

Comment: @VladD ^^^^^^^^

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну это да, тогда асимптотика по точности (или минус логарифму точности, если хотите).

Comment: @Akina, что-то это неправдоподобно.